# How to delete row from gridview with List<> Datasource using OnRowDeleting

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
Gridview.Datasource=List<T>

Gridview.Databind();


protected void Grid_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Where does List<T> (which you use as datasource) come from? And how do you bind it? What have you tried so far? Give us more detail so we can help you.

Comment: This might help: https://www.vanderwaal.eu/mini-projecten/gridview-edit-and-update-demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide much information, but you can use `OnRowDeleting` as follows:

From [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowdeleting)

> The RowDeleting event is raised when a row's Delete button is clicked,
> but before the GridView control deletes the row. This enables you to
> provide an event-handling method that performs a custom routine, such
> as canceling the delete operation, whenever this event occurs.

What you have is that `RowIndex` so first you need to find a related item from your List (Datasource) and remove it and then bind it to gridview again something like this:

```
protected void OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);

    //Assuming resultList is the datasource,
    var itemToRemove = resultlist.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == index); 
    if (itemToRemove != null)
        resultList.Remove(itemToRemove);
    
    Gridview.Datasource = resultList;
    Gridview.Databind();
}
```

Hope it navigates you right direction!

Comment: It worked. Thanks mate. You are such a life-saver.